# how to add custom error messages in modelform widgets in django

Tags: django

these are fields of the model form
    class Meta:

```
    model = Employee
    exclude = ('user', 'created_by', 'is_deleted', 'created')
```

theses are the widgets

```
    widgets = {
        'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('First name')}),
        'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Last name')}),
        'house_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('House name / flat No')}),
        'street_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Street Name / No')}),
        'locality_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Locality Name / No')}),
        'pin_code': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Zip Code')}),
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error messages are not placed inside widgets

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

   class Meta:
       model=Employee
       exclude = ('user', 'created_by', 'is_deleted', 'created')
       error_messages = {
        'first_name': {
            'max_length': _("This writer's name is too long."),
           },
       }
```

Comment: It is not placed in widgets  messages=forms.CharField( error_messages={"max_length":"This value exceeds its max length value"},widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'special'}))

Comment: i am using model form so do i need to define all the fields again in the form to achieve the custom errors or can in be done in widget itself.                                           widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('First name')}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Last name')}),
            'house_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('House name / flat No')}),
     
        }

Comment: Dont do it in widgets if you just want error messages.I have updated my answer

Comment: You dont have to define all fields just pass error_messages in the Meta class @beginners

Comment: is messages another field u have created??

Comment: replace 'messages' with your field name

Comment: i have edited the asnwer!Sorry for confusing @beginners

Comment: Please upvote and approve answer if this helped you @beginners

Comment: why to specify error_mesages again in the field when you have specified it in the meta class

Comment: You dont have to!First read my answer ! You are adding error_messages in Meta Class itself

Comment: thank you for your answer and clarifying the doubts it reallly worked

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#error-messages), you can simply use `error_messages` for that;

```
'first_name': forms.TextInput(error_messages={'required': 'message'}, 
                              attrs={'placeholder': _('First name')})
```

Comment: 'first_name': forms.TextInput(error_messages={'required': 'message'},attrs={'placeholder': _('First name')}),
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_messages'

Comment: Have you tried to use widget in model reference like; 
`class YourForm(forms.ModelForm): 
first_name = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': 'message'}, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('First name')}))`

Comment: by this way i have again specify all the fields in the form so then wat is the use of using model form