# how to override error_message in model or model form?

Tags: django

Sorry for my English. Unfortunately, I can't find a solution on the forum and in google. I ask you to help me figure out how you can override error_mesage in ModelForm or Model. It is necessary that instead of the standard message during validation, it shows the message that I define. I constantly get a message instead of mine "Please fill out this field". Don't be too harsh, I'm a beginner. Please, if possible, explain in detail and with an example. Thanks! Below is the code that I used.

Form

```
    class PersonForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Person
            fields = ('name', 'mood')
            error_messages = {'name': {'invalid': 'Мое сообщение об ошибке', 'blank': 'Мое сообщение '
                              'об ошибке', 'null': 'Мое сообщение об ошибке'}}
```

Views

```
    def exp_index(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            pForm = PersonForm(request.POST)
            if pForm.is_valid():
                pForm.save()
                persons = Person.objects.all()
                pForm = PersonForm()
                add_message = 'Можете добавить еще одну запись!'
                context= {'person': persons, 'form': pForm, 'add_message': add_message}
                return render(request, 'exp/exp_index.html', context)
            else:
                persons = Person.objects.all()
                error_message = 'Неверно указали данные, попробуйте еще раз!'
                context= {'person': persons, 'form': pForm, 'error_message': error_message}
                return render(request, 'exp/exp_index.html', context)
        else:
            pForm = PersonForm()
            person = Person.objects.all()
            context= {'person': person, 'form': pForm}
            return render(request, 'exp/exp_index.html', context)
```

Model

```
    class Person(models.Model):
        l=[[None, 'выбрать значение'],['g', 'хорошем'], ['b', 'плохом'], ['n', 'нормальном']]
        def iterPersonChoices(list):
            for i in list:
                yield i
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, db_column='your_name',
                                error_messages={'invalid': 'Мое сообщение об ошибке', 'blank': 'Мое сообщение '
                                'об ошибке', 'null': 'Мое сообщение об ошибке'})
        mood = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=iterPersonChoices(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML file, instead of using `{{ form.as_p }}`, you should construct the form manually so you can handle the error messages:

Something like:

```
<!-- person_form.html -->
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="{{ form.firstname.id_for_label }}">Prénom</label>
            <input type="text" id="{{ form.firstname.id_for_label }}" name="{{ form.firstname.html_name }}"
                value="{{ form.firstname.value|default_if_none:'' }}"
                class="form-control {% if form.firstname.errors %}is-invalid{% endif %}" autofocus="">
            {% for error in form.firstname.errors %}
            <span class="text-danger">Неверно указали данные, попробуйте еще раз!</span>
            <br />
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="text-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enregistrer</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: And for automatically generated forms {{ form.as_p }}, how can this be done?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53514661/how-to-add-custom-error-messages-in-modelform-widgets-in-django) should help ?